# Scrapy does not follow given requests

Tags: python, scrapy

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import logging

import scrapy
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response


class SuvlistingsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'SuvListings'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.gumtree.com.au']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.gumtree.com.au/s-cars-vans-utes/sydney/carbodytype-suv/forsaleby-ownr/c18320l3003435/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        self.log('Received response for listings page', level=logging.INFO)

        main = response.css('.panel-body.panel-body--flat-panel-shadow.user-ad-collection__list-wrapper')[-1]
        for a in main.css('a'):
            req = response.follow(a, callback=self.parse_item)
            yield req

    def parse_item(self, response):
        0/0
        yield {
            'price': response.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@id="ad-price"]/div/span[1])').extract(),
        }
```

The above code does not trigger the exception. I have it running in debug in Pycharm. It is an anchor selector as stated in the tutorial on the scrapy site, but nothing gets scraped. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `allowed_domains` you must specify just a domain without scheme (www.gumtree.com.au). Otherwise scrapy blocks all "offsite" requests thinking their domain does not match the allowed ones.

Comment: Exactly. No exception but you might see how many requests were filtered in the scrapy stats in "offsite/filtered" or "offsite/domains"

Comment: oh wow, yeah that's it right there: ` 'offsite/filtered': 24,`. Still on the learning curve